# How to wrap label when using ggplot2 in knitr?

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I am generating scatter plot using ggplot2 and exporting to pdf using knitr. Some of the labels are two long and I would like to wrap it into two lines.

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=NA, results='hide'>>=

library("Hmisc")
library("ggplot2")
library("gridExtra")


x1 <- runif(100)
y1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- runif(100)
y2 <- rnorm(100)
test <- data.frame(cbind(x1,y1,x2,y2))
label(test$x1) <- "This is a Variable label for variable x1" 
label(test$y1) <- "This is a Variable label for variable y1" 
label(test$x2) <- "This is variable x2" 
label(test$y2) <- "This is variable y2" 

p1 <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x1, y = y1)) + 
    geom_point(size = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(label(test$x1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(label(test$y1)) +
    geom_smooth()

p2 <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x2, y = y2)) + 
    geom_point(size = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(label(test$x2)) +
    scale_y_continuous(label(test$y2)) +
    geom_smooth()

p3 <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x1, y = y2)) + 
    geom_point(size = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(label(test$x1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(label(test$y2)) +
    geom_smooth()

p4 <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x2, y = y1)) + 
    geom_point(size = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(label(test$x2)) +
    scale_y_continuous(label(test$y1)) +
    geom_smooth()

grid.newpage() 
pushViewport(viewport(width = .8, height = .8, layout = grid.layout(nrow=2, ncol=4)))
print(p1,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))
print(p2,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))
print(p1,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 3))
print(p2,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 4))

@

\end{document}
```

I would like to wrap only label of x1 and y1, how can I do it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To make labels in two lines add `\n` where the text should be broken.

```
label(test$x1) <- "This is a Variable \nlabel for variable x1" 
label(test$y1) <- "This is a Variable \nlabel for variable y1"
```

Comment: I cannot edit the label in my task. What else can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to split the string and reconstruct it.

```
wrap <- function(char,n){
          char1 <- word(char, start = 1, end=n)
          char2 <- word(char, start = n+1, end=sapply(strsplit(char, " "), length)) 
          char <- paste(char1,"\n",char2)
        }

if (nchar(label(data$x0))>20) {
  label(test$y1) <- wrap(label(test$x1),3)
  label(test$y1) <- wrap(label(test$y1),4)
}
```

Comment: See also the `strwrap` function

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `mystrwrap` to wrap strings, with a new line break, at a given `width` such that ggplot can use it as a label.  Wrap the `label()` calls within the `mystrwrap`.  Here is the modified .Rnw file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=NA, results='hide'>>=

library(Hmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)


x1 <- runif(100)
y1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- runif(100)
y2 <- rnorm(100)
test <- data.frame(cbind(x1,y1,x2,y2))
label(test$x1) <- "This is a Variable label for variable x1" 
label(test$y1) <- "This is a Variable label for variable y1" 
label(test$x2) <- "This is variable x2" 
label(test$y2) <- "This is variable y2" 

mystrwrap <- function(x, width = 25) {
  paste(strwrap(x, width = width), collapse = "\n")
}

p1 <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x1, y = y1)) + 
    geom_point(size = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(mystrwrap(label(test$x1))) +
    scale_y_continuous(mystrwrap(label(test$y1))) +
    geom_smooth()

p2 <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x2, y = y2)) + 
    geom_point(size = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(mystrwrap(label(test$x2))) +
    scale_y_continuous(mystrwrap(label(test$y2))) +
    geom_smooth()

p3 <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x1, y = y2)) + 
    geom_point(size = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(mystrwrap(label(test$x1))) +
    scale_y_continuous(mystrwrap(label(test$y2))) +
    geom_smooth()

p4 <- ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x2, y = y1)) + 
    geom_point(size = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(mystrwrap(label(test$x2))) +
    scale_y_continuous(mystrwrap(label(test$y1))) +
    geom_smooth()

grid.newpage() 
pushViewport(viewport(width = .98, height = .8, layout = grid.layout(nrow=2, ncol=4)))
print(p1,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))
print(p2,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))
print(p1,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 3))
print(p2,vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 4))

@


\end{document}
```

The resulting graphic will need some tweaks to the viewport.  (Or, just use `gridExtra::grid.arrange`)
[image]